# file write issue during file handling in c++

Tags: c++, file-handling

While making a program to practice file handling , I am facing an issue. During writing in a file I am seeing wierd stuff like below even I am saving my file in txt format and opening in notepad.

[PIC of file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QFuX.png)

Can anyone clarify?
Here is the code for writing:

```
int hostel::add()
{
int r,flag;
ofstream fout;
fout.open("model",ios::app);
cout<<"\n Enter Customer Details";
cout<<"\n **********************";
cout<<"\n\n Room no: ";
cin>>r;
flag=check(r);
if(flag){
cout<<"\n Sorry..!!!Room is already booked";
fout.close();
}
else

{
room_no=r;
cout<<"\n Name:\t ";
cin>>name;
cout<<"\n Address:\t ";
cin>>address;
cout<<"\n Phone No:\t ";
cin>>phone;
fout.write((char*)this,sizeof(*this));
fout.close();
cout<<"\n Your Room is booked!!";
    }

cout<<"\n Press any key to continue!!";
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Also when reading a file The last record gets printed 2 times:

[reading of file pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2O3K.png)

Code for reading is below:

```
int hostel::rooms()
{
    ifstream fin("model",ios::in);

    cout<<"\n\t\t\tList Of Rooms Allotted";
    cout<<"\n\n Room No.\tName\t\tAddress\t\tPhone No.\n";
    while(!fin.eof())
    {
        fin.read((char*)this,sizeof(*this));
        cout<<"\n\n"<<room_no<<"\t\t"<<name;
        cout<<"\t\t"<<address<<"\t\t"<<phone;
    }

    cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\tPress any key to continue!!";
    system("pause");
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll have to show us the code with which you wrote the file …

Comment: @Programmer I have edited the code

Comment: Did you get that ?

Comment: You may have opened the file in text mode, but you are writing binary into it with `fout.write((char*)this,sizeof(*this));` You are just dumping the internal representation of your class into a file - you can't expect that to come out human-readable.

Comment: Re: the last record being read twice - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). `while(!fin.eof())` is not a right thing to do.

Comment: Yes I saw you added the code, but I couldn't help you on this.